# which is more efficient threading.timer or task parallel library in the era of .net 4.5

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, task-parallel-library

I have designed one application (C# with .net 4.5) which connects to multiple Ethernet enabled hardware devices(Maximum 100 Devices) for data transfer purpose using request response mechanism.

Each hardware device has unique ip address and port configured, my application using tcpclient class connects and communicates with this devices.

Now my requirement is,

1. Make application multi-threaded so that it will be able to connect all the devices at the same time. (Thread per connection)
2. The communication which happens with all this devices is repetitive i.e. after every specific interval it should connect to all devices for data transfer purpose on 24X7 basis.
3. I have one more additional requirement to this is, the interval should be configured once function (callback function) finish the execution. Because some time device delayed the response so I cannot make the use of sleep, delay or equivalent functionality. In this case new iteration may start even if the last iteration was not completed which I want to prevent.

i.e. if I connect to device data transfer should happen and  only after that it should set the interval for next execution.(Most probably in callback function itself)

To achieve this I am thinking to make the use threading.timer, for this I can set the thread interval in callback function itself. I am testing this and seems working initially and I believe I can further optimize this code to work in production environment.

But doing further Google I started believing that task parallel library is more  efficient and since I am working on .net 4.5 I should make the use of this rather than classical threading.timer class.

But since TPL doesn’t have exact equivalent as threading.timer  I will have to work on it to make perfect fit for my requirement.

So my question if i make the use of TPL with some customization rather than threading.timer will I really get any performance gain or should i continue with threading.timer only.

Comment: "*Make application multi-threaded so that it will be able to connect all the devices at the same time*" is a misconception and will lead you down the wrong path. Use async IO, not a thread per connection.

Comment: @spender I got it. Although i am not sure but i believe even if i make the use thread per connection it wont hamper performance much as i have limited connections (May never exceed 100)

Comment: How about no thread at all? IO is asynchronous at the OS level. Blocking is simulated. By using async/await you use the native async functionality without using any thread.

Comment: @BoeseB async/await *is* a feature of TPL.

Comment: @HarshalSam you should reconsider your approach btw. A server connecting *to* 100 IoT devices is a very big security vulnerability. If the device can listen, it can and will be hacked. IoT devices are too weak to mount strong firewalls and antimalware defenses. "But it's inside the company network" doesn't mean it's secure either - it means that any compromised company PC can hack *all* of them.

Comment: @HarshalSam  IoT stacks by Amazon, Azure etc all have the *devices* talk to the server *ONLY*, to upload data, telemetry and receive commands. It's a lot harder to hack a device that *doesn't* accept external connections. It's also a lot better for power/battery consumption. The device only has to power up periodically, instead of being always on awaiting for polls

Comment: @HarshalSam the typical IoT architecture is to use a local queue to collect data and push it to the server periodically. This takes care of connectivity losses and reduces communication and power costs

Comment: This is the kind of thing that Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx) does in its sleep before breakfast. You really should consider using that. It's far more powerful than TPL.

Comment: You seem to be asking about two different things here. Timers will allow you to schedule code and make it run after intervals but it won't help with your need to make multiple connections at once. Timer will call a single method whenever it ticks and that method will then (as I understand it) be responsible for connecting to all the devices ("after every specific interval it should connect to all devices" suggests you have a single timer for all devices). Conversely `Task.Parallel` is suited for doing multiple things in parallel (as the name suggests). Perhaps clarify your intentions for each.

Comment: @Chris for multiple things in parallel, i believe i can make use of multiple threads i.e. threading.timer per connection.

Comment: Ah. So you don't want all the connections to be done on the same timer? I'd read your question as wanting to do all the checks, then once all were done wait a certain amount of time and then do them all again. You are actually happy with having a timer per connection and having them all be independent of each other?

Comment: @Chris yeah each connection will work independently. So my question is if i make the use of threading.timer, still i will get the performance gain as equivalent to i may get with TPL ?

Comment: It just doesn't make any difference, Task.Delay() also uses System.Threading.Timer under the hood to get its job done.  Flip a coin, if it doesn't land on the side you prefer then just flip again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive") for this over both threads and TPL. Here's what I'd do:

Start by defining an array of `TimeSpan` values that can be used to change the scheduling of each device:

```
int devices = 3;

TimeSpan[] timerTimeSpans =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, devices)
        .Select(x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000))
        .ToArray();
```

I've started with a default of 2000 ms.

Then define a method to read from the devices:

```
public Task<DeviceResult> DeviceFetchAsync(int device_number, Action<TimeSpan> reschedule)
{
    if (device_number == 1)
    {
        reschedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
    }

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new DeviceResult()
    {
        DeviceNumber = device_number
    });
}

public class DeviceResult
{
    public int DeviceNumber;
}
```

It includes an `Action<TimeSpan> reschedule` to change the scheduling for this particular device.

Now for the Rx query that sets up all of the timers and reads from the devices:

```
IObservable<DeviceResult> query =
    Observable
        .Range(0, devices)
        .Select(n =>
            Observable
                .Generate(0, x => true, x => x + 1, x => x, x => timerTimeSpans[n])
                .SelectMany(x =>
                    Observable
                        .FromAsync(() => DeviceFetchAsync(n, ts => timerTimeSpans[n] = ts))))
        .Merge();
```

And finally the subscription that sets the whole thing off:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(r => Console.WriteLine(r.DeviceNumber));
```

If you want to stop everything, just do `subscription.Dispose();`.

That's it. That's all the code. I've tested this and it works fine.